# Rename folders Uipath

Tags: directory, automation, rpa, uipath

I want to loop through a folder (which contains several folders) where the folders with a double space in their name are renamed to a single space (for instance; from 'xxxx(double space)xxxxx' to 'xxxx(single space)xxxxx'). I could not find a solution anywhere and I am seeking help here. can anybody give me a clear hint on how to approach this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5LBd.png)

[New code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2s1OO.png)

[Newest code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cB4Ag.png)

Answer (score 1):

That's more of a programming logic rather RPA or UiPath. You have to use something like

```
Directory.GetFiles(selectFolder,”.",SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

This should return all the sub folders under the main folder, further loop through each sub folder and apply the same logic recursively. You also have to split on backslash `\` and get last indexed item to get the actual name of folder without complete path. In the end rename them.

Take a reference from [this](https://forum.uipath.com/t/getting-names-of-all-the-subfolders-inside-a-folder/15497) post from official forum. This is same as your requirement.

Comment: I can get the files and assign them a string, but when I loop through them, it gives me an exception. I tried with Try/Catch activity but it did not work? Please look at the attached image below.

Answer (score 0):

You could either use the MATCH activity and use a regex expression to find your folders you need...

OR

... just straight up loop through the folder collection and rename ALL folders using the string REPLACE function through the MOVEFOLDERX activity. [UiPath.Core.Activities.MoveFolderX]

psudeo ex:

```
FOR EACH <activity> 
     (item) in iFolderNameList
{
   MOVE <activity> 
       path = item
       to = item.Replace("  ", " ")
}
```

Hope that helps get you started :)

Comment: I have attached an image below.

Comment: Click on the renaming file link in my answer from today.

Comment: 1. you'll need to add an exception to the try catch
2. once you do, can you provide any ex it throws?

Comment: The exception it threw was: the first folder not recognized, but I clicked on continue on error = true which made the exception go away but now the loop is going through the folders without changing the names?

Comment: I tried attaching the workflow, but I was not able to attach the file. Can't you look at the image I have sent you?

Comment: sorry man i meant for you to use MoveFolderX (UiPath.Core.Activities.MoveFolderX). youll have to add it to packages. MoveFile wont move folders; hence your errors

Comment: kindly see the newest attachment. It says that I have to choose a different directory path. I simply can not replace it with the other folder.

Comment: in this case, you could do one of two things. 1. create a tmp folder in the directory you're working in and move the renamed folders there, then move them back. 2. Create new folders, move the contents, then delete the old folder name. If the folder contents are not large, i would suggest the first option. Otherwise, use the latter suggestion to limit the dual IO read/writes.